# C# | Animated GIF from URL flickers and stops showing

Tags: c#, image, winforms, picturebox, gif

I have an animated GIF sourced from a URL in a PictureBox but it flickers for a second or so and then disappears giving me this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the URL is correct? Try to right-click it -> properties and check the URL.

Comment: The URL is fine, it shows the animated image fine and then flickers and stops showing it.

Comment: _The URL is fine, it shows the animated image fine and then flickers and stops showing it. _ ??? Do you mean this happens on the Website? Or have you downloaded the file and this happens in the PictureBox? What happens when you view it with an imageviewer?

Comment: Don't worry, it has stopped happening